# Can’t resolve all parameters for Component:(?) Ionic2 RC4

Tags: angular, ionic2

Dears, 
I know that question is repeated but really i tried all available solutions but still can't solve my problem.
I have multiple components and a service I imported the service to components like signin,signup,..etc.
but i have one component that make the problem and if i removed the service injection from it application will run perfect.

the Invalid component is :

Activation.ts

```
import {Component,Injectable,Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {CloudAuth} from '../../shared/auth_service';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-activation',
  templateUrl: 'activation.html'
})
export class Activation   {
  constructor( @Inject(CloudAuth) public _CloudAuth:CloudAuth ){

  }
}
```

one of worked components login.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams, LoadingController, AlertController, AlertOptions, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
 import {FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {TranslateService} from "ng2-translate";

import {Facebook} from 'ionic-native';
 import {CloudAuth} from '../../shared/auth_service';


@Component({
  selector:'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class login {

  constructor(public loading: LoadingController, public navCtrl: NavController, public params: NavParams,
              public _userService: UserService, public _FormBuilder: FormBuilder, public translate: TranslateService,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController , public _CloudAuth:CloudAuth) {
 ........... 
  }
 ...........

}
```

My service code is auth_service.ts:

```
import {Injectable , Inject} from "@angular/core";
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';
import {TranslateService} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';

import {Activation} from '../user/activation/activation';
import {welcomePage} from '../welcome/welcome';
import {userLogin} from '../user/user';
import {CompleteRegistration} from '../user/completeRegistration/completeRegistration';
import {HomePage} from '../home/home';

@Injectable()
export class CloudAuth {

  jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
  token=null;
  constructor(
    @Inject(TranslateService) public translate: TranslateService , 
    @Inject(Platform)  public platform: Platform
  ){
          this.token = localStorage.getItem('user_token');
  }

      getToken(){
        return this.token;
      }
      updateToken(newtoken){
        localStorage.setItem('user_token', newtoken.toString());
        this.token = newtoken;
        return true;
      }
      isTokenExpired(){
          // Check if token expired
          return this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.token)
      }
      tokenData(){
         // Return data stored in token
          if(this.token=='' || this.token == null) return false;
          else return this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.token);
       }

       checkCode(code){
          let userData =  this.tokenData();
          if( userData == false) return false;
          else {
              if(userData.activation_code == code) return true;
              else return false; 
          }
       }

      // Check if user login or not and loading the default app Language.
      checkLogin():any{
        console.log(this.token);
        let lang = localStorage.getItem('Language');
        if(!lang || lang==''|| lang === undefined ) return welcomePage;
        else {
          if(lang=='ar'){
                this.platform.setLang('ar',true);
                this.platform.setDir('rtl',true);
          }
          this.translate.use(lang);
          let userData =  this.tokenData();
          if( this.token==null ||  this.token== '' || userData == false) return userLogin;
          else {
              if(userData.active == 1) {
                  if(!localStorage.getItem('firstRun') ){
                    return CompleteRegistration;
                  }else{
                    return HomePage;
                  }
              }else {
                  return Activation;
              }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

I removed @Inject decorator but also not working.

My package.json is :

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.25",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
     "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng2-translate": "^4.0.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.47",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "pecardPlayground: An Ionic project"
}
```

My node and ionic information is :

```
Ionic Framework: 2.0.0-rc.4 
Ionic Native: 2.2.11 
Ionic App Scripts: 0.0.47 
Angular Core: 2.2.1 
Angular Compiler CLI: 2.2.1 
Node: 6.7.0 
OS Platform: macOS Sierra
```

this error dose't appear before it happened since upgrade to Ionic RC4
hope to find a solution.
Thanks

Comment: can you include package.json

Comment: Thanks @SurajRao I updated the question with package.json file

Comment: in your auth service where is localStorage set?

Comment: yes, I'm not using Ionic-storage. just native localStorage.

Comment: also it works fine with other components

Comment: what do you mean by where is it injected ?

Comment: `import {CloudAuth} from '../../shared/auth_service';` are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: yes its correct its the same on login.ts page and it works fine.

Comment: final question..have you imported auth_service in welcomePage,HomePage or CompleteRegistration ?

Comment: Will put up the answer once I get response

Comment: yes it also imported their, .

Comment: Activation is your starting page right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a case of Circular Dependency.
You have imported `Activation` component in `auth_service` and have imported 
`auth_service` in `Activation` which is your starting page.
use [forwardRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#forwardref)

```
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => CloudAuth)) _CloudAuth)
```

in your constructor in Activation.
 Another tutorial link [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html)

Edit:
Also could rethink design if possible.